# border-radius почему не работает?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, border

```css
p.one {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid deeppink;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 80px 50px;
}

p.two {
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid depppink;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">Proin ut class Malesuada cum consequat suspendisse sed pharetra, suspendisse, ultricies. Nam vulputate faucibus. Hendrerit fringilla tortor magnis dis litora, convallis ante montes habitasse sapien Est nisl. Congue morbi torquent.</p>
<p class="two"><br><br><br></p>
```

У меня два вопроса:
1) Почему при такой записи:

```
border-top-right-radius: 80px 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 80px 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 80px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
```

Всё работает как надо, а при такой:

```
border-radius: 80px 50px;
```

Выдаёт не тот результат? Как я понимаю эти две записи эквивалентны или я не прав?

2)
Почему не отображается второй абзац? Должен получиться круг, но вообще ничего не отображается

Comment: «вообще ничего не отображается» — потому что depppink это некорректный цвет, правильно deeppink

Comment: @andreymal аааа да точно)

Answer (score 1):

Почему в этом коде у вас указано два значения?
Ведь вы конкретно говорите какой угол и какой радиус.

```
border-top-right-radius: 80px 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 80px 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 80px 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 80px 50px;
```

Вторая запись работает верно, там можно указать сразу 4 значения, по аналогии с padding.

По второму абзацу, поменяйте цвет бордера. `border: 5px solid deeppink`

Comment: Все радиусы сразу так можно поставить

Comment: Как я понимаю первая запись(border-radius: 80px 50px) устанавливает border-radius для всех углов верно?